# Why does Chrome itself allow websites to access chrome-extension://*?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, fingerprint

The article from [here](https://securityboulevard.com/2019/11/how-to-detect-browser-extensions-3/) shows a method for websites to determine whether a user has a particular extension installed, if "web_accessible_resources" (in case of Chrome) allows this. My question is why do browsers not filter these requests themselves? The only use case I came up with was to fingerprint the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of an extension lists such accessible resources in its manifest.json intentionally. This is a feature used by extensions to add a UI or a font/image to the web page(s) and so on.

Fingerprinting is possible only due to a poor implementation in Chrome (and Chromium-based browsers), which will be eventually [fixed](https://crbug.com/1133624) in ManifestV3 so extensions can set `use_dynamic_url`.

Firefox WebExtensions aren't affected because Firefox uses a unique per-machine UUID, [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources#using_web_accessible_resources).